# iOS Screen Capture Pause

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, screen-capture, avassetwriter

I am trying to record the screen using AVAssetWriter .
I can successfully start and save the screen video.
Now I would like to implement an action "Pause".Can any please guide me how can I implement this.
Here is my screen capture code .

```
NSError* error = nil;
videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[self tempFileURL] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

//Configure video
NSDictionary* videoCompressionProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1024.0*1024.0], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                       nil ];

NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                               nil];

videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];

NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
NSDictionary* bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

avAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes];

//add input
[videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];
```

Some one suggest me to record multiple files and merge it .Is it a proper way ?I think video merge will take some time .

Please give me some suggestion .

Thanks

Comment: I am also doing the same thing like you. I can pause and continue for 1 time. I am also trying to solve for pausing and continue recording more than 1 time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866429/avassetwriter-assetwriterpixelbufferadaptor-pause